# Using contains method on visualforce page

Tags: contact, list-view

I am having a set of string. I need to check whether that set contains a particular value or not. I want to check it on visualforce page and without iterating over the set. Can i do this? Can i do this for list or map or any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call any parameterized functions from VissualForce page as far as i know. 
for [Reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11784/how-to-call-parametrized-function-from-visualforce) -

Comment: But we can use size directly on VF page myList.size

Comment: size don't take any parameter that's why.