# Formatting numbers in Apex:outputtext to include space between numbers

Tags: visualforce

Below is the code used to display Amount where thousand separator is comma :

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,###}"> <apex:param value="{!family.totalSalesPlanAmount}"/> </apex:outputText>
```

Original number: 12123
RESULT after formatting: 12,123

But i want to display thousand seperator as space. Eg: 12 123 (french format)
i have tried below codes but not able to achieve success:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{0, number, ###&nbsp;###&nbsp;###&nbsp;###}">
```

it gives me result: 12123&16

Can you please help me to format the number in french format where thousand separator is space

Comment: Check this link, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56613/outputtext-number-formating-with-space-a-thousand-separator