# How to display content of remote text file in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, outputtext

I am trying to display the contents of a remote text file on a Visualforce Page.
I have implemented a class called MyApexClass containing a getTextFileContentAsString method that returns the content of a remote text file as a string.

I then try to invoke that method in the Visualforce page and display it with apex:outputText like so "{!MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString}". However, I get an error saying:

```
Error: Unknown property MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString referenced in MyTemplate.
```

What is the correct way to invoke the method, and get the returned string to render on the VisualForce page?

Here are the Apex Class and the VisualForce page excerpts:

**Apex Class:**

```
public class MyApexClass {

  public String getTextFileContentAsString() {
    String url = 'http://somehost.com/theTextFile.txt';
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    return res.getBody();
  }
}
```

**VisualForce Page excerpt:**

```
...
<div>
<apex:outputText value="{0}">
<apex:param value="{!MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString}" />
</apex:outputText>
</div>
...
```

Do I need to do anything special to make the MyApexClass "visible" to the VisualForce page?

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to method bindings made in your Visualforce page check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11784/how-to-call-parametrized-function-from-visualforce

Comment: I have now removed the parameter and hardcoded the URL, as user320 suggested. However, I am still stuck with the "Unknown function MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString. Check spelling." error.

Comment: Remove parenthesis also

Comment: Have you referenced your controller class in the apex:page tag?

Comment: Hi Keith, that turned to be the key point. Once I referenced controller class in the apex:page tag, it works. My concern now is - would explicitly specifying the controller break previous behaviour? How do I know which controller was being picked up when the controller class was not specified explicitly in the page tag?

Comment: Specifying a controller explicitly is how the page is hooked up to your Apex code for {!xxx} binding expressions; there is no implicit controller class.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is just fine. It's just lacking an exclamation mark, and the argument should be removed, try:

```
<apex:param value="{!TextFileContentAsString}" />
```

Then hard-code the URL into the req.setEndpoint in your Apex class. (Visualforce getters cannot have parameters)

Comment: Hi, when I put the exclamation mark, I get:
Error: Unknown function MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString. Check spelling.

Comment: Make sure you have the method implemented in your code and it returns the string.

Answer (score 0):

This {!}, is the syntax for merge fields in visualforce. I guess you are missing '!'.  You can also cast responce body to string, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Remove () after method name

```
<apex:outputText value="{!TextFileContentAsString}">
</apex:outputText>

Public class yourController{
   //getter method of controller
   public string getTextFileContentAsString{
     return MyApexClass.TextFileContentAsString();
   }   
}
```

Comment: I now get an Unknown property error instead. I suspect my class is not visible because somehow, the VisualForce page is not "associated" with it. Something to do with "controllers"?

Comment: If TextFileContentAsString is not the get method of controller, then you need to define a getter that interns call TextFileContentAsString to get the string value